# Global constants in Laravel / Vue3 / InertiaJS app

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-10

What is the best way to declare a constant that can be accessed in any of the .vue pages in a Laravel 10 / Vue3 / Inertia 1.0 application ? Just a simple string, like `abc = 'def'` that will display on any .vue page like: `{{ abc }}`

I thought maybe the app.js file would be a good place to put it, but I cannot work out the correct way to do this. It doesn't need to be accessed by any php files.

I would have thought that this would be quite a simple thing - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the data changes and comes from the backend just use shared data.
https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#accessing-shared-data

Otherwise just have a file which exports it

```
export const abc = "def";
```

and then just import it in your vue script

```
import { abc } from "@/js/data";
```

Comment: Thanks - I'd already done something like that, but was trying to find a way to avoid having to import the same thing on every single page in the site, maybe by putting something in app.js.